# How can I debug what is causing my computer to lock up?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, freeze, rsync

My wife's computer has been running Ubuntu 9.04 32-bit, but now she has 6GB of RAM, so I tried upgrading to Ubuntu 9.10 64-bit. She has a AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4800+ and 64-bit Ubuntu will install, but if I try to use rsync to copy files from my computer, her computer locks up immediately. If I don't rsync, the computer takes a few minutes before it locks up. I also tried 64-bit 9.04 and it had the same problem. I ran memtest86 and it says there is no problem with the memory. what else can I do to figure out what is causing the problem?

note: each install was a clean install and i use rsync to restore her files.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked `/var/log/messages` for kernel and system logs? It may give insight into what happened leading to the lockup.

The [SYSSTAT Utilities](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/) are also great for monitoring performance of a Linux box all around. From CPU to memory, Disk I/O and networking. They will help you pinpoint what's causing the random lockup if it is a slow buildup of resource usage.

A complete tutorial on their usage is found [here](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Does your Ubuntu system have `strace` installed? If so, preface your `rsync` command with `strace` to see the system calss being made. This is likely to generate a *lot* of noise but might give you a clue where it's locking up.